# How to debug a traceless crash

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging, c++builder

During development of out application we have in special encountered a really nasty bug. The symptom is quite simply that the process disappears. The logs just end abruptly, no crash dumps or anything can be found, no zombie processes exist. Dr.Watson haven't noticed anything leaving us without any trace.

The error is not simple to reproduce, it takes on average 3-4 hours to reproduce this error, doing the same actions repeatedly. So somewhere there is some kind of race condition. We have special functions handling both SEH and normal exceptions so none of these should go unnoticed.

The debugging must be done on a special computer, because it is running on very specialized hardware. So only remote debugging is available. And when remote debugging is connected C++ builder doesn't noticed that the application is missing, and crash and burns when we try to do any debugging on the non existent process.

We are using a great variety of technologies with this software:

- OpenGL
- Directshow + some COTS filters
- COM/DCOM
- Serial COM ports talking to specialized hardware
- C++ Builder (which uses different stackframes than VC++)

So, as you understand, I do not have much to work with here. What I am doing now is that I am trying to narrow it down by logging in different places in the code to find if there is some particular point in the code the error occurs. I am also trying to remove as many aspects of the action I am performing to get the case as simple as possible. But this is a really complex operation and this process is taking a lot of time, and time is (as usual) a scarce resource.

I am wondering if anyone out there have good tips for me, either to the cause (in general what causes a process just to stop without any notification) or to techniques for debugging such an elusive failure?

Comment: I hereby name this class of bugs "Bermuda Triangle Bugs".

Comment: What exact version of Windows are you running this on?

Comment: This is running on a customized Embedded XP.

Comment: @caf hehe, I have actually named this bug The Ninja bug, because it kills the process and disappears without a trace :D

Answer (score 7):

When native code under Windows experiences a stack overflow (typically due to infinite recursion) the process sometimes disappears exactly as you describe. The standard error dialogs and exception handling require some stack space, and where there is none left they cannot run. (Later versions of Windows handle this better and *should* always raise an exception - Windows XP is not "later" under this definition.)

The easiest brute-force way to debug this is to write log messages at the entry (and maybe the exit) to each function. These messages *have* to go directly to a file, and if you have buffered output (eg. `cout` or similar) you should flush it immediately each time. When you manage to cause the crash, you'll have close to a stack trace that can at least localise the issue.

---

Infinite recursion is not the only cause of a stack overflow (though it is the more common one). If very large variables (typically arrays with thousands/millions of elements) are allocated on the stack the same issue may occur. In particular, the `alloca()` "function" can disguise the cause of this type of stack overflow.

If you run under a debugger and break/log on guard page exceptions you will be notified when the stack is expanding - let the exception be handled, since it is being used to commit more memory and may not actually be related to the issue.

---

The final non-stack-overflow cause of a disappearing process is a stray call to `exit()` or `ExitProcess()`. A full text search should be able to mostly rule this out - a breakpoint on the `ExitProcess` function in a debugger will do so completely.

Comment: +1 for mentioning to write your own trace logs. Every bit of logging information is like Gold when trying to debug something obscure!

Comment: You might be right, but we have setup structured exception handling (SEH) which the OS should notify if a stack overflow should occur. Also in earlier cases I have seen stack overflows, they usually make both dr.watson react and pop up notifications that the process has been killed. The cout debugging is what I am doing now. Hopefully it will yield some results.

Comment: @daramarak It's system dependent. I just wrote a short test app (in assembly, `start: push 0 jmp start`) and it raises `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW` on Win7 x64 but just disappears on WinXP x86. Another thing you can try is reducing the stack limit (should be in linker options) and seeing if the error occurs sooner.

Comment: +1, ok I will investigate this further. Will try to recreate a stack overflow to see if this really goes undetected.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you try windbg, it can also connect remotely via a named pipe or serial port.

---

**NO BSOD, no Rootkit , no Fun ~~
Biswanth Chowdhury - Win32 Kernel***

Comment: I guess that windbg will get problems with the unfamiliar stackframes, but still if it gives me an adress that is more than I have now. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Googling `windbg Borland` shows that you can get function names but not variable names.

Comment: @MSalters, Thank you I didn't know that. I have tried other vc++ sentric tools earlier but the haven't yielded much information, but knowing this I will definitely try it.

Comment: Try using breakpoints in windbg wherever u think that the executing statement changes the program logic.

Comment: @MSalters : Windbg is Microsoft Windows's not Borland. And if the module is build with debug information, it can show the variable names also. Please read carefully before answering

Comment: I did. Borland C++ Builder targets Microsoft Windows. WinDbg is not the deubgger for Microsoft Visual C++, but for Microsoft Windows. However, WinDbg cannot read every debug information file format in the world.

Comment: @MSalters: Fine, what u r trying to say is "The Debugger for VC++" , which is itself an ide-n-debugger , what I am saying is Windbg (aka Microsoft WinDbg) .As far as I know it "CAN" sufficiently debug "BETTER" than VC++ . I do not underestimate u but as a Kernel Developer, I can see that Windbg is better and it would serve this "small" purpose. For your seference -- [It is a GUI application, but has little in common with the more well-known, but less powerful, Visual Studio Debugger.-- Wikipedia ]

Comment: @Biswanath Chowdhury : No, I did not say, and I did not intend to say the VC++ debugger. I am fully aware of the difference with WinDBG, having both installed in parallel on my machine. The VC++ debugger understands C++ far better, but WinDBG understands the x86 far better.

Comment: @MSalters: C++ compiles into processor-specific instruction, not just x86, and if u can debug as assembly instruction, then u can even debug KiKernelTrap ;) not just c++. By the way, good posts, enjoyed the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Try running it with a smaller heap. If the problem is due to the fact that you run out of memory, this will cause the crash to happen sooner.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to debug the scenario more often, try running this in a Virtual Machine and taking "snapshots" every so often before it happens.

The problem here could be inconsistency with the states of the specialized hardware you mention you have connected via serial port.

Comment: First of all the hardware makes it virtually (no pun intended) impossible to virtualize the environment. Secondly I cannot understand how the state of the hardware might affect our process. It is only accessed through the serial port. So an error inside that might cause hangs of the firmware, communication problems, but termination of the process???